# How to use lock-free FIFOs in multi-threading?

Tags: data-structures, multithreading

Computer-science wisdom says that a lock-free FIFO (queue) is the right way to synchronize shared data between **two** threads in a lock-free manner. I know what a queue is and how the lock-free property is accomplished, however: how a FIFO queue solves the problem? How to practically use it? What data should go into it?  Could you provide some pseudo-code?

Comment: Does [an answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2945444/240613) answer your question?

Comment: @ArseniMourzenko that's definitely a good start. Thank you!